# need to change local folder git repo to another different git repo

Tags: git, github

I have a folder that was backed up in a common git repository (`git1` repo).
We have now made that just a repo to keep final versions of files, and set up individual Git repositories for working files (`git2` repo).
The hope was things would stay cleaner this way. The git repositories are completely separate and not branches of the same.

The problem I have is that I am not able to figure out how change which Git repo my working folder backs up to.
I created a new folder and then copied the contents of the old folder into this new one (`cp` command). Now when I do git push and put the address of the new git repo (`git2` repo) it gives a fail message

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/git2repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I do `git status` I get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

And when I do `git remote -v`:

```
origin  https://github.com/git1repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/git1repo.git (push)
```

It gives the same git address for `fetch` and `push` that are the previous one that we set up (`git1` repo)- not the new one I am trying to push to now (`git2` repo)).

Not sure how to change where the folder gets pushed to, and I obviously do not want to change anything in the `git1` repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you want to push, it is better to push to a bare repo, that is a repository *without* any file (no working tree), only the .git content.

```
git init --bare dest
cd /path/to/repo/to/backup
git remote add backup /path/to/bare/repo/dest
git push --mirror backup
```

More generally, I changed *where* to push by specifying the repository 'backup' to my git push command: see [`git push <repository>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push-ltrepositorygt).

If one needs to fix the URL behind the existing remote named 'origin', as the OP did, consider:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/git2repo.git 
git remote -v
  backup https://github.com/git2repo.git (fetch) 
  backup https://github.com/git2repo.git (push) 
  origin https://github.com/git2repo.git (fetch) 
  origin https://github.com/git2repo.git (push)
```

Comment: when i try this, it keeps the origin the same previous repo and makes a new backup  that has the new git.  instead, what i ended up doing was:  

    `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/git2repo.git`

then when i checked with    `git remote -v`:  

    `backup  https://github.com/git2repo.git (fetch)
    backup  https://github.com/git2repo.git (push)
    origin  https://github.com/git2repo.git (fetch)
    origin  https://github.com/git2repo.git (push)`
  
Not sure if this has fixed the issue, or if i have opened up other ones without realizing.

Comment: @rpanam That is the same as my answer, except you are using the remote named origin.